# What is the best way to execute CGI scripts with root privileges?

Tags: bash, apache2, cgi, root

As the title says, I'm looking for a method to run a CGI script (running on APACHE on Ubuntu) with root privileges.

In particular, some commands of the script can be executed by the current user (`apache`), but other commands need root privileges (as `iptables`).

I can also write "sub-scripts" containing these privileged commands, but the problem of executing them with root privileges still remains.

I'm also confused about wether to write the CGI in C or PERL or bash script language. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best method is to use **sudo** for such scripts. You must specify which commands can run the script in this case.

In /etc/sudoers:

```
wwwdata    ALL=(ALL) /usr/local/bin/allowed-operation
```

And then in the script:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/allowed-operation
```